# Unable to get hyperlink in SOQL query

Tags: soql, hyperlink

On Account record I have a text field that gets updated from Apex class with value as 'Click [here](https://www.google.com)' where 'here' is a hyperlink to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). On querying the field using SOQL, I am getting the value as 'Click < a href="www.google.com" > here< /a >'.

But I want to get the value as 'Click [here](https://www.google.com)'(with hyperlink) instead of href. Is it possible? Please suggest if it can be achieved by any other method.

Comment: Salesforce prevents HTML rendering in many cases to avoid injection attacks. You would probably need to handle this in a custom way.

Comment: if you are using a visualforce page, you can simple use an  outputtext with escape=false: <apex:outputText value="{!myTextField}" escape="false"/>

Comment: I am not using it in visualforce page. I need to use it inside messaging template for sending SMS on mobile. Is there any other way to handle?